# how to call api in background after 5 minutes?

Tags: ios, swift

My application listen for a bluetooth device to fire an event when the application is in background mode and then calls an api. I want to call the same api after 1 minute and again call that api after 5 minutes when the application is in background mode.

Comment: Have you tested an answer below?

Comment: yes i have tested it and its working more fine then DispatchSourceTimer but still some time its takes more than 5 minutes in for second call

Comment: Try to build 2 requests with different durations. You can call that DispatchQueue in `func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)` in AppDelegate

Comment: can you provide me code sample if possible ?

Comment: i have updated an answer. Try to call `registerBackgroundTask(60)` in foregroud case. Also you need to customize block within `{ print("fasdf") }` with what you need. Also will be helpful some var describing `background` state.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you turn on the background mode and set needed values in xCode. It is strange, but even if background mode is turned off, this code works. I use this code:

In AppDelegate add code below:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    registerBackgroundTask(60)
    return true
}

func registerBackgroundTask(_ durationSec : Double = 60 ) {
    let duration : DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + durationSec
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: duration, qos: .background) {
            print("fasdf")
            // customize it!
        }
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    application.beginBackgroundTask {[weak self] in
        self?.registerBackgroundTask(5 * 60)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this code currently but its working some times and some times its not working. Any other solution would be appreciate.

Comment: I have not found any solution yet but you solution is quiet helpful right now. Thanks bro